# speeding up web page load (2)

Tags: sql, arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I've asked a similar question before in which I received responses to fix my multidimensional array to receive records faster with getrows. There are over 36 000 records returned into this multidimensional array. Although previous answers of my other question did not seem to speed up my page my much.

I am then using this multidimensional array to check if certain id's match then attach permissions to content.

So my multidimensional array -

```vb
'MultiDimensional Array
Dim permissionsArray
Dim permissionsCount  
connectionstring = obj_ADO.getconnectionstring               

Set c = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set r = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
r.CursorLocation = 2 'adUseServer
c.open connectionstring
c.CursorLocation = 2 'adUseServer

SQL = "select OP_ObjectID, P_Name from l_objectpermission inner join A_Permission on op_permissionID = P_permissionID order by P_Name"

Set r = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
r.CursorLocation = 2 'adUseServer
r.Open SQL, c, 0, 1 'adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
If r.BOF or r.EOF Then
   r.close()
   Set r = Nothing
Else
   permissionsArray = r.GetRows()
   permissionsCount = UBound(permissionsArray, 2)
   r.Close()
   Set r = Nothing
End If
c.Close()
Set c = Nothing
```

Then content and id's + using multidimensional array to attach permissions

```vb
    while obj_ADO.EOF(lng_RecSet) = 0           
%>
                <tr>
<%
        objID = obj_ADO.GetField("O_ObjectID", adValue, lng_RecSet)
%>
                    <td align="center" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="selectedRecord" value="<%=objID%>"></td>
                    <td valign="top" align="left"><font class="Content1"><%=obj_ADO.GetField("O_Name", adValue, lng_RecSet)%></font></td>
                <td valign="middle" align="center"><center><div style="text-align: left; width: 180px;">
                 <%
                for i = 0 to (permissionsCount)
                    if permissionsArray(0, i) = objID then
                        %>
                        <li style="height: 2px;">
                        <%=permissionsArray(1,i)%>
                        </li>
                        </br>
                        <%
                    end if                        
                next   
                %>
                </div></center></td>
        </tr>
<%
        obj_ADO.MoveNext(lng_RecSet)
    wend
    obj_ADO.CloseRecordset lng_RecSet
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by changing what was loaded into the multidimensional array. Instead of loading everything I loaded by whatever the user filters by

```
if str_Prefix = "" then
    SQL = "select OP_ObjectID, P_Name from l_objectpermission inner join A_Permission on op_permissionID = P_permissionID order by P_Name"
elseif str_Prefix <> "" then
    SQL = "select OP_ObjectID, P_Name from l_objectpermission inner join A_Permission on op_permissionID = P_permissionID where P_Name like '" & str_Prefix & "' + '%' OR P_Name like '% ' + '" & str_Prefix & "' + '%' order by P_Name"
else
    SQL = "select OP_ObjectID, P_Name from l_objectpermission inner join A_Permission on op_permissionID = P_permissionID order by P_Name"
end if
```